# How to exclude a specific userID (user) from the database in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on the user profile page of my app, where the user can make changes to the user info, like change their username, name... Each user has their own unique username, I have done that with the following code:

```
// Function to check if the username is taken
static func checkUsernameUnique(newUserName: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Username").queryEqual(toValue: newUserName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

This checks if there is a user with the same username. Calling this function:

```
checkUsernameUnique(newUserName: username) { isExist in
    if isExist {
        print("Username is taken")

    } else {
        print("Username is not taken")

    }
}
```

The problem with this is that this checks if there is a user using the same username with all the other users in the database, including the **current user**. How do I exclude the current user?

[image: My database]

**Code that I tried with the help of one of the answers**

```
static func checkUsernameUnique(newUserName: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

        print(userID)
        ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Username").queryEqual(toValue: newUserName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

            if !snapshot.exists() {
                completion(false)

            } else {


                //Here we will check the given user's UID
                snapshot.ref.child("UserID").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (uidSnapshot) in
                    //This forced cast should never fail
                    let uid = uidSnapshot.value as! String
                    print(uid)
                    //Now we use FirebaseAuth to cross reference the current user's UID with whatever the "Username" node's sibling node "UserID" is
                    if Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid == uid {
                        //The returned user is the same as the current user
                        completion(false)
                    } else {
                        //The returned user is not the same as the current user
                        completion(true)
                    }
                })

            }
        })

    } else {

        ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Username").queryEqual(toValue: newUserName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted a comment earlier, but thought you were wanting to compare uid and not username. Comparing username will be a little more difficult. What you'll need to do is query for that username and then get the entire User object, i.e. Email, Full Name, Profile Picture URL, UserID, and Username. If you can do this, then we can compare UserID with `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` to see if the user returned is the current user.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: The problem is the logic sequence: If you want to guarantee that each user has a unique username, you should query for the username they want to use *before writing it to the database*.

Comment: @Jay yes I am calling this function when signing the user up, so that the users should come up with unique usernames, and also I am allowing the users to change their username in my editUseProfile page, so this is where I’m running into this problem

Comment: Not sure that's clear. If you allow the user to select a username when they first create their account, before writing that data to Firebase, you should query to see if it exists. Likewise, if they want to change their username later, query for it before writing it to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. All we have to do is get the userID of whatever is returned from the query, and check if it equals the current user's uid.

```
// Function to check if the username is taken
static func checkUsernameUnique(newUserName: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Username").queryEqual(toValue: newUserName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        guard let json = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        //Assuming there will never be more than one database entry with this username, this first element (result) can be unwrapped explicitly without crashing
        let result = json.first!.value

        let userID = result["UserID"] as! String

        if Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid == uid {
            completion(false)
        } else {
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to conditionally exclude data from a query.  You will have to check in your client code if specific data is present in the result, and exclude it from there.  Just checking snapshot.exists will not be sufficient in your case - instead, look inside the snapshot to see if it contains the UID of the current user.